# Swiperjs control multiple sliders speed

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I want to meet the WCAG 2.1 criteria and allow users to change the speed of the sliders. I'm using swiperjs on my page. I was able to make it work for the first slider, but not for the second one. I'm assuming it is because the const defaultSpeed with refers only to the headerSlider. I don't know how to change it to work for both of them.

```js
const customSlider = document.getElementById('custom-slider');
const sliderThumb = document.getElementById('slider-thumb');

// Initialize the headerSlider
const headerSlider = new Swiper('.header__slider', {
    speed: 400, // Default speed (milliseconds)
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000, // Default autoplay delay
        disableOnInteraction: false, // Prevent autoplay from stopping on interaction
    },
    effect: 'fade',
    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.slider__pagination',
        clickable: true,
        bulletActiveClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet-active--white',
        bulletClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet--white',
    },
});

// Initialize the aboutSlider
const aboutSlider = new Swiper('.about-us__slider', {
    speed: 400, // Default speed (milliseconds)
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000, // Default autoplay delay
        disableOnInteraction: false, // Prevent autoplay from stopping on interaction
    },
    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.about__pagination',
        clickable: true,
        bulletActiveClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet-active--white',
        bulletClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet--white',
    },
});

// Calculate the initial position of the slider-thumb based on default speed
const minSpeed = 2000; // Minimum speed (milliseconds)
const maxSpeed = 100; // Maximum speed (milliseconds)
const defaultSpeed = headerSlider.params.speed; // Use headerSlider's default speed
const initialPosition = ((defaultSpeed - minSpeed) / (maxSpeed - minSpeed)) * (customSlider.clientWidth - sliderThumb.clientWidth);

// Set the initial position of the slider-thumb
sliderThumb.style.left = initialPosition + 'px';

let isDragging = false;

sliderThumb.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDragging = true;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveSlider);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', releaseSlider);
});

function moveSlider(e) {
    if (!isDragging) return;

    const sliderRect = customSlider.getBoundingClientRect();
    const newPosition = e.clientX - sliderRect.left;

    // Constrain the thumb within the slider bounds
    const minPosition = 0;
    const maxPosition = sliderRect.width - sliderThumb.clientWidth;

    if (newPosition >= minPosition && newPosition <= maxPosition) {
        sliderThumb.style.left = newPosition + 'px';

        // Calculate and update the speed based on the thumb's position
        const range = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
        const speed = Math.round((newPosition / maxPosition) * range) + minSpeed;

        // Update both headerSlider and aboutSlider's autoplay speed
        headerSlider.params.speed = speed;
        headerSlider.autoplay.stop();
        headerSlider.autoplay.start();

        aboutSlider.params.speed = speed;
        aboutSlider.autoplay.stop();
        aboutSlider.autoplay.start();
    }
}

function releaseSlider() {
    isDragging = false;
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveSlider);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', releaseSlider);
}







// Event listeners for play and stop links
const playButton = document.querySelector('.slider__play');
const stopButton = document.querySelector('.slider__pause');

playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    headerSlider.autoplay.start();
    playButton.style.display = 'none';
    stopButton.style.display = 'block';
});

stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    headerSlider.autoplay.stop();
    stopButton.style.display = 'none';
    playButton.style.display = 'block';
});


const aboutPlayButton = document.querySelector('.about-slider__play');
const aboutStopButton = document.querySelector('.about-slider__pause');

aboutPlayButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    aboutSlider.autoplay.start();
    aboutPlayButton.style.display = 'none';
    aboutStopButton.style.display = 'block';
});

aboutStopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    aboutSlider.autoplay.stop();
    aboutStopButton.style.display = 'none';
    aboutPlayButton.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
.header__slider {float:left;}

.slider__play:before, .slider__pause:before {content: "";
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
  mask-size: 100%;
  }
  
  .slider__controls {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  width: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  .slider__controls {
    padding: 24px;
  }
}
.slider__controls--orangeBg {
  background-color: #f79422;
}
.slider__controls--whiteBg {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.slider__play-stop-btn {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 32px;
}
.slider__play, .slider__pause {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.slider__play--orange:before, .slider__pause--orange:before {
  background-color: #f79422;
}
.slider__play--white:before, .slider__pause--white:before {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.slider__play:before, .slider__pause:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 20px;
}
.slider__play {
  display: none;
}
.slider__play:before {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(../../dist/img/icon-play.svg);
  mask-image: url(../../dist/img/icon-play.svg);
}
.slider__pause:before {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(../../dist/img/icon-pause.svg);
  mask-image: url(../../dist/img/icon-pause.svg);
}
.slider__change-speed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 32px;
}
.slider__speed-btn {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider__pagination {
  height: 20px;
}
.slider__pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet--white {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.slider__pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet--orange {
  border: 2px solid #f79422;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.slider__pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet-active--white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.slider__pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet-active--orange {
  background-color: #f79422;
}

.slider__pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet--white, .slider__pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet--orange {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  border-radius: 96px;
}

.header-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.header-slider__carousel {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.header-slider__item {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header-slider .swiper-slide-active p {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.header-slider__img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  .header-slider__img {
    height: 600px;
  }
}
.header-slider__controls {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 7px;
}

.about-us__slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.about-us-slider__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.about-us-slider__controls {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<p>header slider</p>
<div class="header__slider header-slider">
               
    <ul class="header-slider__carousel swiper-wrapper">
        <li class="header-slider__item swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/230914102757-01-rucking-workout-wellness-stock.jpg?c=16x9&q=h_438,w_780,c_fill"  class="header-slider__img"/>
        </li>   
        
         <li class="header-slider__item swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/230912152507-02-ariana-grande-botox-fillers-vogue-screenshot.jpg?c=16x9&q=h_720,w_1280,c_fill"  class="header-slider__img"/>
        </li>  
    </ul>
    
    <div class="header-slider__controls slider__controls slider__controls--orangeBg">
        
        <div class="slider__play-stop-btn">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider__pause slider__pause--white" role="button" aria-label="Click to stop the slaider" title="Click to stop the slaider"></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider__play slider__play--white" role="button"  aria-label="Click to start the slider" title="Click to start the slider"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="custom-slider" class="slider__change-speed" role="slider" aria-label="Change the speed of the slider">
            <div id="slider-thumb" class="slider__speed-btn" tabindex="0" aria-valuemin="2000" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="400"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="slider__pagination"></div>
    </div>
  
</div>


<p>About slider</p>
<div class="about-us__slider">
  <ul class="about-us-slider__carousel swiper-wrapper">
    <li class="about-us-slider__item swiper-slide">
       <img src="https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/230912193551-27-mtv-vmas-red-carpet-fashion-2023-taylor-swift.jpg?c=16x9&q=h_720,w_1280,c_fill" class="about-us-slider__img"/>
     </li>
     <li class="about-us-slider__item swiper-slide">
       <img src="https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/230912103239-paul-pogba-juventus-090323.jpg?c=16x9&q=h_720,w_1280,c_fill" class="about-us-slider__img"/>
     </li>     
  </ul>
        
 <div class="about-us-slider__controls slider__controls slider__controls--orangeBg">
                            

                            <div class="slider__play-stop-btn">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider__pause slider__pause--white about-slider__pause" role="button" aria-label="Click to stop the slaider" title="Click to stop the slaider"></a>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider__play slider__play--white about-slider__play" role="button" aria-label="Click to start the slider" title="Click to start the slider"></a>
                            </div>

                            <div id="custom-slider" class="slider__change-speed" role="slider" aria-label="Change the speed of the slider">
                                <div id="slider-thumb" class="slider__speed-btn" tabindex="0" aria-valuemin="2000" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="400"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="slider__pagination about__pagination"></div>
                        </div>

</div><!-- __slider -->
```

Comment: I dont see the diff between the two sliders. Can you make it more obvious?

Comment: Added working images to the sliders. The problem with the second slider is that you can't move the speed handle at all. Where at the first slider you can speed or slow down the change of the slides. The change of speed at the first slider affects the second one